# java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large

Tags: java, android, methods

In application I have an error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':buildPropTweakerPro:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
 > java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
```

but I don't have any classes, that was bigger than 64KB.

Gradle version, what I use, is 2.3.3

When I use gradle version 3.0.0 I have an error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':buildPropTweakerPro:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
 > java.lang.ClassFormatError (no error message)
```

My build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {

compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    versionCode 19
    versionName "1.3.3"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError true
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:3.6.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
}
```

I searched many questions on internet, but do not have any answers, but in the error, I do not have answer, in what file I have too large method.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

disable instant run in android studio settings

Comment: glad ,if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Just Enable `Multidex`

```
android {    
 defaultConfig {
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
  }  
}
```

Comment: share your **`Build.Gradle`**